# Multiple regression to only output residuals in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, regression

I'm currently working on a project where I need the residuals of a multiple regression in VBA.

I'm using the following code to run the multiple linear regression. Where my y variable is in R11:R376 and the X range is in S11:U376.

I want the final output to look like this:

[image]

I run the regression like this:

```
Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Regress", 
ActiveSheet.Range("$R$11:$R$376") _
    , ActiveSheet.Range("$S$11:$U$376"), False, False, , ActiveSheet.Range( _
    "$X$11"), True, False, False, False, , False
Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False
```

Which gives me this output:

[image]

However, I want only the residual serie. Is there a way in VBA to not output all other information? I could of course just delete the part of the output that I don't want but the problem is that I don't want the output to appear on the screen. I have tried

```
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

But I still get the output to show. So basically I want to run a multiple linear regression in VBA where only the residuals appear. As always, help is highly appreciated.

Comment: `ScreenUpdating = False` does not let the user to see what happens when the code runs. It must be `True` when code ends. Otherwise, you will not see what the code returned. I do not think that the functions can be "convinced" to return in the way you need, only playing with its parameters. But you can write a piece of code to search for the range you need, copy it were you want and then clear the rest of the function return. i can try posting an answer doing what I suggested above. I will use A:A as Target column, B:D (B1 to B3 values) and E:E to return 'Residuals'. Would that be convenient?

Comment: This may be a silly question (and I am certainly not a stats guru), but if you are only interested in the residuals from the linear regression (and not all the associated statistics and tests) why not use the LINEST() spreadsheet function? That will give the coefficients for each X variable (oddly in reverse order, read the Help!) and the intercept. Then it is a simple calculation to find the model predicted, Y, and determine the difference from your observed Y. You can do this in VBA, or simply on your spreadsheet itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next code, please. I used the columns as I mentioned in my comment. I firstly copied your first four rows values and copied them down up to 257 rows. Of course, you must adapt the code for the ranges you are using:

```
Sub testRegression()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, celRes As Range, lastRowR As Long, rngDel As Range
 Dim rngTarg As Range, rngDat As Range, rngRet As Range, arrRes
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 Set rngTarg = sh.Range("A2:A257") 'the target range
 Set rngDat = sh.Range("B2:D257")  'values to be processed
 Set rngRet = sh.Range("G2")       'where to return (Regress function)
 
 Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Regress", rngTarg, rngDat, False, _
                False, , rngRet, True, False, False, False, , False
         
   Set rngDel = Selection  'the returned range area is selected and
                           'take advantage of this aspect
   'find the cell keeping the string "Residuals":
   Set celRes = rngDel.Find(What:="Residuals", After:=rngRet, _
                LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
   If Not celRes Is Nothing Then
       'determine the last row of the "Residuals" column:
       lastRowR = sh.cells(sh.rows.count, celRes.Column).End(xlUp).row
       'put "Residuals" values in an array (header included):
       arrRes = sh.Range(celRes, sh.cells(lastRowR, celRes.Column)).Value
       rngDel.Clear        'clear the initial returned range
     With rngRet.Offset(-1, -1)
        'drop the array values at once:
        .Resize(UBound(arrRes), UBound(arrRes, 2)).Value = arrRes
        .Select
     End With
   End If
End Sub
```

Please, send some feedback after testing it...

Comment: Works perfectly thanks. Clever idea to set the regression output as a range and then find the residuals in that range.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach: Excel provides a spreadsheet function for multiple linear regression, LINEST()

If you just want the residuals (and none of the regression statistics), you can wrap LINEST in a user-defined spreadsheet function:

```
Option Explicit

'Array spreadsheet function to perform Linear Regression and return residuals
Public Function LinestResiduals(rngY As Range, rngX As Range) As Variant
    Dim vX As Variant
    Dim vY As Variant
    Dim vLinest As Variant
    Dim vResidual As Variant

    Dim lValues As Long
    Dim lCoeffs As Long

    vX = rngX
    vY = rngY
    
    lValues = UBound(vX)
    lCoeffs = UBound(vX, 2)
    
    vLinest = Application.WorksheetFunction.LinEst(vY, vX, True)
    
    ReDim vResidual(1 To UBound(vY), 1 To 1) As Variant
    
    Dim lVal As Long
    Dim lCoeff As Long
    Dim d As Double
    For lVal = 1 To lValues
        d = 0
        'Oddly the LinEst function returns the coeffs in reverse order
        For lCoeff = 1 To lCoeffs
            d = d + vLinest(1 + lCoeffs - lCoeff) * vX(lVal, lCoeff)
        Next lCoeff
        
        'Find residual, including intercept
        vResidual(lVal, 1) = vY(lVal, 1) - d - vLinest(lCoeffs + 1)
    Next lVal
    
    LinestResiduals = vResidual
End Function
```

Here's an example in action:
[image]

NB: This only handles data that is organized in columns. Extra code is required if data might be organized in rows.